# Eigenvector of a matrix with complex entries?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have $A = \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & -2 \\
        1 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$. Its eigenvalues are $2 + i\sqrt{2}$ and $2 - i\sqrt{2}$. I've found its characteristic equation to be $\lambda^2 - 4\lambda + 6 = 0$.

To find the eigenvector, I started with $\begin{pmatrix}
        2 - \lambda & -2 \\
        1 & 2 - \lambda \\
        \end{pmatrix}x = 0$.

Then I used case $\lambda = 2 + i\sqrt{2}$, which gave me $\begin{pmatrix}
        -i\sqrt{2} & -2 \\
        1 & -i\sqrt{2} \\
        \end{pmatrix}x = 0$.

However, by Gaussian elimination, I found $(2i\sqrt{2})x_2 = 0.$ Meaning $x_2 = 0$ and therefore $x_1 = 0$. But the solutions given to me stated that the eigenvectors for $\lambda_\pm$ were $u_\pm = (1, \mp\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}})$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Your Gaussian elimination is wrong. You should find the second row is eliminated to become all zeros.

Comment: You have $-i\sqrt{2}x_1-2x_2=0$ and $x_1-x_2i\sqrt{2}=0$ .If you multiply the first equation with $\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}$, you get the second. Hence, you can choose $x_1=1$, for example.

Comment: Silly mistake by me. But how does that give me the eigenvectors from the solutions?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm missing something, but does that mean I can choose any $x_1$?

Comment: @Deanaf Yes, you can choose every real value except $0$